# AjaxPro Not Running On .Net Framework 4.0 and Server 2008 / IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajaxpro

I'm using AjaxPro & AjaxControlToolkit in my project. My project is normally running on Server 2003 with IIS 6. But when i loaded my project on Server 2008, i'm getting "AjaxPro undefined" error. My project is working .Net Framework 4.0 Classic mode.

I tried [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/04/14/ajax-net-and-iis-7-integrated-mode.aspx) but my project isn't working still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this code on web and tried this;

```
<location path="ajaxpro">
    <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
           <add name="*.ashx_*" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro.2" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
       </handlers>
     </system.webServer>
</location>
```

and it works normally on IIS 7 & Server 2008 & .Net Framework 4.0 & Classic Mode.